# probability - picking 2 letters one after another

Tags: probability

I had this question on my mind. I want to know if I am using the correct idea and process.

> Find the probability of picking 2 letters one after another from a bag containing all the letters in the alphabet so that they turn out to be 'X' and 'Y' in any order.

First lets pick a letter. We need an 'X' or a 'Y'. But in the second turn there are only 25 cards left, and we need to pick a 'Y' if we picked 'X' the first time and vice versa. So according to me the probability should be:

$$P(n) = \frac{2}{26} * \frac{1}{25} = \frac{1}{325}$$

Am I right? Am I doing it the right way?

Comment: You did it excellent.

Comment: @drhab Is my logic right too?

Comment: Yes. You could make it: "but in the second turn there are - *under condition that indeed an X or Y was picked in the first turn* - et cetera". The second factor, i.e. $\frac1{25}$,  is a conditional probability.

Comment: Your approach is fine. Another one: there are ${26\choose2}=325$ ways to select 2 objects (order not important) from 26. Of these only one selection ({X','Y'} is fine, so probability is $1/325$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scetch of your correct thinking:

Let $L_1$ denote the first letter that is picked and $L_2$ the second. Then:
$$P\left(\left\{ L_{1},L_{2}\right\} =\left\{ X,Y\right\} \right)=$$$$P\left(L_{1}\in\left\{ X,Y\right\} \right)P\left(L_{2}\in\left\{ X,Y\right\} \mid L_{1}\in\left\{ X,Y\right\} \right)=\frac{2}{26}\frac{1}{25}$$

Comment: what does the $|$ indicate?

Comment: Conditional probability. On the right side of | you see the condition. If this is new to you then just forget about this. The main thing here is that your intuition works well. The second factor gives the probability that the second letter is $X$ or $Y$ under the condition that the first has turned out to be $X$ or $Y$.